# Кавычки в текстовом поле input

Tags: php, html

Привет. Сразу перейду к делу. Есть следующий код:

```
$test = "Каждый 'охотник' желает знать.";
// $test = addslashes($test); // это не помогло
echo "<input type='text' value=' " . $test . " ' />";
```

Как видно из этого кода, в тексте имеются одинарные кавычки. Данный текст через переменную вставляется в текстовое поле. Атрибут value заключён в одинарные кавычки. Получается что одинарные кавычки, находятся внутри других одинарных кавычек. При выводе на страницу, текст в текстовом поле, урезается до первой кавычки. Аналогичная ситуация наблюдается и в случае, если вместо одинарных кавычек, будут двойные кавычки.

Данные в это текстовое поле вставляются из БД. Посему я не могу знать, какие именно кавычки нам попадутся в тексте. Как правильно вставить кавычки в текстовое поле? Есть ли в PHP что-нибудь полезное для таковых ситуаций?

Answer (score 6):

Зачем рисковать - [вот](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php) хорошая функция `htmlspecialchars`.

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете использовать функцию [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Answer (score 2):

При выводе **любой** строки на страницу ее желательно обработать функцией [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php), если только не предполагается, что она должна содержать в себе кусок HTML-разметки:

```
echo "<input type='text' value=' " . htmlspecialchars($test) . " ' />";
```

Answer (score 1):

Чисто ради разнообразия ответов: можно заменять все кавычки (из БД) одного типа на другой. Например все одинарные кавычки заменять двойными при выводе, а в инпуте использовать одинарные.

Самый на мой взгляд правильный вариант - использовать фреймворк который сам будет думать о такой проблеме (и множестве других).

Comment: Как предложено из вариантов с помощью htmlspecialchars($test, ENT_QUOTES) мы заменим кавычки на HTML cущности. Но ведь при последующей отправке на сервер и последующей записи этого текста в БД, стало быть придётся раскодировать этот текст обратно. Как это можно сделать? Есть вариант с html_entity_decode(), но так ли обычно решаются подобные задачи?

Comment: Как я уже писал - лучше использовать фреймворк. Это не должно быть вашей головной болью. Смотря что вы храните. Если например код - лучше ничего не менять вообще, а если просто комментарии, например, то просто меняйте на html и не думайте лишний раз.

Comment: А мне не хочется использовать фреймворк. Хотелось бы обойтись штатными средствами. Наверняка PHP имеет в своём арсенале всё для этого необходимое. На одном из форумом по программированию, давали совет, относительно хранения текста в БД. А именно, в БД нужно хранить только оригинальный текст, без всяких преобразований. Преобразования должны происходить только в момент вывода текста на страницу.

Comment: Да имеет, в конце концов фреймворк же будет написан на PHP :) Другой вопрос что чтобы предугадать все возможные проблемы вам придётся написать свой фреймворк. Так не лучше ли использовать то что написали много-много умных людей с многолетним опытом работы?

Comment: @stashappy "придётся раскодировать этот текст обратно" Вы ошибаетесь - не придется. При отправке значений через запрос они кодируются другим алгоритмом и прозрачно декодируются интерпретатором `php`. А вот перед вставкой в базу нужно будет экранировать другие символы

Comment: @tutankhamun, но это же в корне меняет дело. А какой параметр в php.ini отвечает за эту замечательную возможность, прозрачного декодирования текста?

Comment: @stashappy Так это по-умолчанию работает. Насколько я понимаю это даже невозможно отключить. Есть еще `magic_quotes` но это, на мой вгляд, полнейшая чушь и почти везде отключено (я дополнительно через .htaccess чаще всего отключаю)

Comment: @tutankhamun, magic_quotes я его тоже через htaccess отключил. Насчёт декодирования текста, подумалось о возможности включения этого параметра(если таковой имеется в php.ini) через htacess на постоянную основу. Но если вы говорите что такого параметра не существует, то остаётся только дело за малым - грамотно вывести текст на страницу с помощью htmlspecialchars(). Чтож. Благодарю всех за отклик. Продолжаю свой путь...

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) например:

```
$test = "Каждый 'охотник' желает знать.";
$testClean = htmlentities($test, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401);
echo "<input type='text' value=' " . $testClean . " ' />";
```

Comment: `htmlentities` - избыточная функция для указанной цели. Мне кажется хорошей практикой является использование двойных кавычек в качестве ограничителей значений аттрибутов и экранирование символов ', ", >, <, & (что и делает функция `htmlspecialchars`)

Comment: @tutankhamun да, в данном случае достаточно `htmlspecialchars`.